# What does this.__chart__ refer to in a d3 selection?

Tags: d3.js

I've been poking around in [d3.box](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/box/box.js) and [d3.bullet](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/bullet/bullet.js). In both cases, the current scale is retrieved using something like the following...

```
var x0 = this.__chart__ || d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, Infinity])
  .range(x1.range());
```

...where `x1` is the current scale object. I realise that this idiom is used to update the box plot or bullet chart, but could anyone explain how? What does `this.__chart__` refer to? A scale object? Why the conditional? (`||`) Why does `x0`'s domain cover the range 0 to infinity when the current scale is unlikely to have such a large range?

Apologies if my questions are poorly specified. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` context is the DOM element that contains the chart: i.e. a `g` element. Binding some variable to the DOM element, e.g. `this.myvar = state`, provides a way to deal with chart specific state. Multiple update calls on one specific chart g element, will then all have access to the same variable.

Mike and Jason have used the property name `__chart__` in various charts and also in the [d3 axis component](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js), for keeping track of chart specific state.

You're right that in this case it's the scale that is being stored in the g element's `__chart__` property. See excerpt from bullet.js:

```
  // Compute the new x-scale.
  var x1 = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, Math.max(rangez[0], markerz[0], measurez[0])])
      .range(reverse ? [width, 0] : [0, width]);

  // Retrieve the old x-scale, if this is an update.
  var x0 = this.__chart__ || d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, Infinity])
      .range(x1.range());

  // Stash the new scale.
  this.__chart__ = x1;
```

So, a scale `x1` is determined based on the current data. It will be stored in `__chart__`, to be used some time in the future when this chart is updated with new data.

The previous scale is taken from `this.__chart__` and kept in `x0`. The `this.__chart__` will return `undefined` when the chart is just being constructed (i.e. the enter phase). In that case `x0` will instead become `d3.scale.linear().domain([0, Infinity]).range(x1.range())`. See [short circuit eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

The old scale is needed for smooth transition. When new data points are entered, we first want to plot them on the chart using the old scale. After that we will transition all points (new and updated) according to the new scale.

Regarding the [0, Infinity] domain. So, a scale with this domain will only be used when the chart is just constructed. That means it provides a way to setup the initial transition when introducing the chart. A infinite domain with a finite range means that all points are scaled to 0. So, when the chart is set up, all points will be plotted at 0 and transition to the proper values according the x1 scale.